# onselected event in md-select in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I would like call a function in typescript on choosing a value using md-select. What is the property used for this purpose in material design ?

```
   <md-select placeholder="State">
       <md-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.code">{{ state.name }}
   </md-option>
```

Answer (score 202, accepted):

**For Material version >= 6**

Use the **`(selectionChange)`** event on **`mat-select`**.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="State" (selectionChange)="someMethod($event.value)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.value">
            {{ state.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In the event method, **`$event.value`** contains the currently selected **`[value]`**. Reference to the [**official documentation**](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api).

> @Output() selectionChange: EventEmitter< MatSelectChange >
>
> Event emitted when the selected value has been changed by the user.

Here is a link to [**Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-stackoverflow-9wpyd8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fstackoverflow-solution%2Fstackoverflow-solution.component.html).

---

**For Material version < 6**

Use the `(change)` output event.

```
<md-select placeholder="State" (change)="someMethod()">
  <md-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.value">
    {{ state.viewValue }}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Another way is to use `(onSelectionChange)` event on `<md-option>`:

```
<md-select placeholder="State">
  <md-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.code" 
             (onSelectionChange)="anotherMethod($event, state)">
    {{ state.name }}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Link to [**Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kzhjqm?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: (change) has been renamed to (selectionChange)

Comment: We can also modify the first option like `(change)="someMethod($event)"` and then in code we can retrieve the selected value like `$event.value`.

Comment: with every version syntax is changing. its no longer funny

Comment: I ended up needing to use `(selectionChange)="someMethod($event)"`

Comment: @checketts, I have updated the answer accordingly. :)

Comment: Where is written, that you need to use the variable with the $ prefix? Can not find it anywhere in the documentation...

Comment: What if you want to fire event only when some values were selected and md-select was closed?

Comment: What if i want to pass value instead of ($event)? Shall i use #value for that purpose?

Comment: @Samavi you can pass `$event.value` in that case

Comment: I am really grateful for your response. By ($event) i mean i have method getInstructorbyCourse(CourseId : number) and in mat-select i am using #course will i pass course.value?

Comment: @Samavi you don't have to use `course.value`. See the first code sample in the answer. You can wither set `[value]="course"` or `[value]="course.courseId"` and depending on that, your event on `mat-select` will look like `(selectionChnage)="getInstructorbyCourse($event.value.courseId)"` or `(selectionChange)="getInstructorbyCourse($event.value)"`

Answer (score 6):

Just adding on for people using latest version of material and searching for the solution, change md to mat in the answer suggested by @Faisal.

```
<mat-select placeholder="State" (change)="someMethod()">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.value">
    {{ state.viewValue }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

for material version greater than 6 use `(selectionChange)` instead of `change`

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you can just use the `(click)` event on `mat-option`. The click event is also fired when an already selected option is selected again. `(change)` or `(selectionChange)` will not fire in such a case.

Comment: For future readers, it is preferred not to use `(click)` at dropdowns because dropdowns can be navigated from buttons too. (For example down and up buttons). In these cases, the `(click)` event won't be fired. That means your handler won't be called. Using `click` events on dropdown is also a big accessibility anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

html

```
<mat-label>Select a Category</mat-label>
<mat-select formControlName="category" name="category 
         (selectionChange)="onChangeCategory($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.value">
            {{category.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Typescript

```
onChangeCategory(event) {
    console.log(event.value);
}
```