# Getting first value as "undefined" while retrieving selected material radio button value using ngModel

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I'm using angular 6 and material components where i have  made a radio button group in which there are two options given to select in which i have used ngModel to get the value of selected radio button but getting undefined value on the first click and getting previous selected value while clicking another option Please Help Code is given below:-

**App.Component.html**

```
<mat-radio-group formControlName="offers" [(ngModel)]="offers">
<mat-radio-button value="freeShipping" (click)="offerStatus(offers)">Free shipping</mat-radio-button>
<mat-radio-button value="nextDay" (click)="offerStatus(offers)"> Next Day</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

**App.component.ts**

```
  offerStatus(data){
  console.log(data);
}
```

**Output**

```
undefined //when selecting any one of the options

freeShipping //when selecting nextDay option

nextDay //when selecting freeShipping
```

**Expected Output**

```
freeShipping // when selecting freeShipping

nextDay // when selecting nextDay
```

Comment: is below solution worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `change` instead of `click`

```
<mat-radio-button value="freeShipping" (change)="offerStatus(offers)">Free shipping</mat-radio-button>
```

Comment: Bro Still getting the same problem when changing click event to change

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362951/material-radio-button-change-event-angular-4?answertab=active#tab-top