# How do I implement an Angular Material mat-select change event?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to implement the following bootstrap select in Angular Material. How do I implement the change event shown here in bootstrap?

```html
<select (change)="sortByProducts($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let filter of filters" [value]="filter.id">
    {{filter.title}}
  </option>
</select>
```

How do I add the change event to material that calls the sortByProducts function as done in the code segment shown above?

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let filter of filters" [value]="filter.id">
      {{filter.title}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: did you try `<mat-select (change)="sortByProducts">` with `sortByProducts(event)` in your ts file ?

Comment: Yes I did. Doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onselected event in md-select in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036204/onselected-event-in-md-select-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a selectionChange output that you can use :

```
// html
<mat-select (selectionChange)="sortByProducts($event.value)">

// ts
sortByProducts(value) {
    console.log(value)
}
```

See https://material.angular.io/components/select/api